Step variables not being recognized
image: node:20 definitions:   caches:
    pnpm: $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/.pnpm-store
    node: node_modules/**
    nextjs: $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/web/.next/cache

  yaml-anchors:
    - &install-pnpm-script >-
      npm i -g pnpm && pnpm ci:prepare

  clone:
    depth: full    # SonarQube Cloud scanner needs the full history to assign issues properly

  services:
    docker:
      memory: 3072
    postgres:
      image: postgres:16
      variables:
        POSTGRES_USER: prisma
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
        POSTGRES_DB: tests

  steps:
    - step: &deploy
        oidc: true
        name: Deploy
        services:
          - docker
        caches:
          - node
          - pnpm
          - nextjs
        run-once: true
        script:
          - echo $STAGE


pipelines:   branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Staging
          <<: *deploy
          variables:
            STAGE: test    options:   max-time: 30   size: 2x   docker: true

With this pipeline I was expecting STAGE to be present and printable inside deploy step, but it is not. How can I do that?

This question is similar to: Use variable for Bitbucket custom pipeline deployment value. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Beware white spaces in your code block were mangled, it'd be nice if you [edit] the question to fix that. Also, you should post a minimal reproducible example instead of your whole bitbucket-pipelines.yml

it is not similar @N1ngu, the person was asking about pipeline input variables, I'm asking about step ENV VARIABLES.

Isn't it a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/q/74228716/11715259 then?
